# How to read multiple sheets with Event model using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I can successfully read Excel file (.xls) using Event model POI.  I am not using the usermodel (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel) but an Event API to process xls and xlsx files (to address the memory footprint issue). However, when reading an .xls file with multiple sheets, only first sheet is read. Other sheets are ignored.

I am implementing HSSFListener and overriding its processRecord(Record record) method for xls files.

Here is my part of the code:

```
/**
     * Main HSSFListener method for xls. It processes events and creates a RuntimeRecord to put into the DataPool.
     */
    public void processRecord(Record record) {
        int thisRow = -1;
        String thisStr = null;

        switch (record.getSid()) {
            case BoundSheetRecord.sid:
                boundSheetRecords.add(record);
                break;
            case BOFRecord.sid:
                BOFRecord br = (BOFRecord)record;
                if(br.getType() == BOFRecord.TYPE_WORKSHEET) {
                    // Works by ordering the BSRs by the location of their BOFRecords, and then knowing that we
                    // process BOFRecords in byte offset order
                    if(orderedBSRs == null) {
                        orderedBSRs = BoundSheetRecord.orderByBofPosition(boundSheetRecords);
                    }

                    // Check the existence of sheets
                    if(sheetIndex == 0) {
                        for(int i=0;i<excelSheetList.length;i++) {
                            boolean found = false;
                            if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NAME)) {
                                for(BoundSheetRecord rec : orderedBSRs) {
                                    int len = rec.getSheetname().length();
                                    if(len > 31)
                                        this.warning("processRecord()","The length of sheet: " + rec.getSheetname() + " has more than 31 characters. Please change the name of the sheet, save the file and try again.");
                                }
                            }

                            if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NUMBER)) {
                                int sheetNo = Integer.parseInt(excelSheetList[i]);
                                if(sheetNo > 0 && sheetNo <= orderedBSRs.length) {
                                    found = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                for(int j=0;j<orderedBSRs.length;j++) {
                                    if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NAME)) {
                                        String sheetName = ((BoundSheetRecord) boundSheetRecords.get(j)).getSheetname();
                                        if(excelSheetList[i].equals(sheetName)) {
                                            found = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(!found)
                                this.error("processRecord()","Sheet: " + excelSheetList[i] + " does not exist.");
                        }
                    }

                    readCurrentSheet = true;
                    sheetIndex++;
                    System.out.println(sheetIndex);
                    if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NAME)) {
                        String sheetName = ((BoundSheetRecord) boundSheetRecords.get(sheetIndex-1)).getSheetname();
                        if(!canRead(sheetName)) {
                            readCurrentSheet = false;                       
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(!canRead(sheetIndex + "")) {
                            readCurrentSheet = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case SSTRecord.sid:
                sstRecord = (SSTRecord) record;
                break;

            case BlankRecord.sid:
                BlankRecord brec = (BlankRecord) record;

                thisRow = brec.getRow();
                thisStr = null;
                values.add(thisStr);
                columnCount++;
                break;

            case FormulaRecord.sid:
                FormulaRecord frec = (FormulaRecord) record;

                thisRow = frec.getRow();
                if(Double.isNaN( frec.getValue() )) {
                    // Formula result is a string
                    // This is stored in the next record
                    outputNextStringRecord = true;
                    nextRow = frec.getRow();
                } else {
                    thisStr = formatListener.formatNumberDateCell(frec);
                }
                break;  

            case StringRecord.sid:
                if(outputNextStringRecord) {
                    // String for formula
                    StringRecord srec = (StringRecord)record;
                    thisStr = srec.getString();
                    thisRow = nextRow;
                    outputNextStringRecord = false;
                }
                break;

            case LabelSSTRecord.sid:
                if(readCurrentSheet) {
                    LabelSSTRecord lsrec = (LabelSSTRecord) record;
                    thisRow = lsrec.getRow() + 1;
                    if(rowNumberList.contains(thisRow + "") ||
                            (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && thisRow >= secondLastRow)) {
                        if(sstRecord == null) {
                            thisStr = "(No SST Record, can't identify string)";
                        } else {
                            thisStr = sstRecord.getString(lsrec.getSSTIndex()).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NumberRecord.sid:
                if(readCurrentSheet) {
                    NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
                    thisRow = numrec.getRow() + 1;
                    if(rowNumberList.contains(thisRow + "") ||
                                (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && thisRow >= secondLastRow)) {
                        // No need to format.
                        // thisStr = formatListener.formatNumberDateCell(numrec); // Format
                        thisStr = String.valueOf(numrec.getValue()); 
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Handle missing column
        if(record instanceof MissingCellDummyRecord) {
            thisStr = "";
        }

        // If we got something to print out, do so
        if(thisStr != null) {
            values.add(thisStr);
            columnCount++;
        }

        // Handle end of row
        if(record instanceof LastCellOfRowDummyRecord) {
            if(readCurrentSheet) {
                int currentRow = ((LastCellOfRowDummyRecord) record).getRow() + 1;
                if(rowsReadSet.add(String.valueOf(currentRow))) {
                    if(processTestData) {
                        try { 
                            int dpSize = this.getOutputDP().getSize();
                            if(dpSize < 1000 &&
                                    (rowNumberList.contains(currentRow + "") ||
                                            (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && currentRow >= secondLastRow))) {
                                for(int i=columnCount; i<this.getConfigRecord().size(); i++) {
                                    values.add(null);  // Add empty string for missing columns
                                }   
                                RuntimeRecord resultRecord = this.createRuntimeRecord(values);
                                this.fireRecordCreatedEvent(resultRecord);
                                this.putNextRecord(resultRecord);   
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            this.error("processRecord()",e.getMessage());
                            this.fireRecordCreationFailedEvent(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {

                            if(rowNumberList.contains(currentRow + "") || (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && currentRow >= secondLastRow)) {
                                for(int i=columnCount; i<this.getConfigRecord().size(); i++) {
                                    values.add(null);  // Add empty string for missing columns
                                }
                                RuntimeRecord resultRecord = this.createRuntimeRecord(values);
                                this.fireRecordCreatedEvent(resultRecord);
                                this.putNextRecord(resultRecord);

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            this.error("processRecord()",e.getMessage());
                            this.fireRecordCreationFailedEvent(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                values.removeAllElements();
                columnCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the method that registers the listener:

```
private void readxls() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(this.getFileName()));
        MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener listener = new MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener(this);
        formatListener = new FormatTrackingHSSFListener(listener);

        HSSFEventFactory factory = new HSSFEventFactory();
        HSSFRequest request = new HSSFRequest();

        request.addListenerForAllRecords(formatListener);
        rowsReadSet.clear();
        factory.processWorkbookEvents(request, fs);
    }
```

When I debugged by adding some breakpoints, I noticed that it actually adds the column values to my `values` Vector. However, following condition is never matched for second sheet.

```
if(record instanceof LastCellOfRowDummyRecord) {
...
}
```

How to get rid off this problem? I want to read all the sheets in Excel file (.xls). I am using Apache POI 3.11-20141221 with JDK7.

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Tested with POI 3.13-20150929. The problem exists. I think I am missing some condition in my code. The control is not entered into the if-block mentioned in the question. Or does the issue lie at POI?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the code behind the POI XLS -> CSV eventmodel converter. Your code looks quite a bit more complex than that, and I'm not sure why... That code works, follow that!